# What is the name of the variable containing the current chapter title?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, books

Consider a chapter in a french book defined by:

```
\chapter{Blablabla}
```

It will generate the output:

> Chapitre I : Blablabla

Then, we have the following variables:

- `\chaptername` corresponds to **Chapitre**
- `\thechapter` corresponds to **I**

Question: what is the variable containing the chapter title **Blablabla**?

Comment: Strictly speaking, these are macros, not variables. But, in any event, this depends on the document class in use, so please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @PaulGessler In the standard classes, there is no such macro, is there? `\leftmark` includes the name of the chapter but it also includes the other parts of the mark. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @cfr You didn't miss anything :-) But it can be given a name if need be.

Comment: @Vincent You really should look at `titleps` and `titlesec` as Bernard suggested.

Comment: What about `\@title{}`?

Comment: If you use `titlesec` it is very simply `\chaptertitle`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Document classes

The standard classes `report` and `book` and the KOMA-Script classes `scrreprt` and `scrbook` do not store the chapter title in macros.

Class `memoir` uses three internal macros for the chapter title and its variations for the table of contents and the header lines:

```
\chapter[title in table of contents][title in header line]{title in body}
```

Then the internal macros contain:

```
\f@rtoc -> title in table of contents
\f@rhdr -> title in header line
\f@rbdy -> title in body
```

## Packages

There are packages, which support to reference chapter titles.

- Package `nameref`:

  ```
  \chapter[title in table of contents]{title in body}
  \label{chap:label}
  ```

  Then `\nameref{chap:label}` yields "title in table of contents".
  The name is stored in the internal macro `\@currentlabelname`
  (until it is overwritten by the next title).
- Package `titleref`:

  ```
  \chapter[title in table of contents]{title in body}
  \label{chap:label}
  ```

  Then `\titleref{chap:label}` gives "title in table of contents".
  The name is stored in the internal macro `\TR@currentTitle` (until
  overwritten).
- Package `zref-titleref`:

  ```
  \chapter[title in table of contents]{title in body}
  \zlabel{chap:label}% \zref@label or \zlabel with package zref-user
  ```

  Then "title in table of contents" is stored by `\zref@titleref@setcurrent` in property `title` in macro `\zref@titleref@current`.

Comment: What is the name of the file with the manual of zref-titleref?

Comment: @KeksDose `zref` is the main project.

Comment: If scrreport does not store the title in a macro, what is the macro used to print the title of the current chapter in the header when using `\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}`?

Answer (score -2):

There seems to be a terrible lack of modularity and compositionality in all this. Here's my situation: I am formatting a book, which has the chapter title *without the chapter number* as the heading on odd-numbered pages. (This is, incidentally, a very common feature in book designs: I had a quick look at books on my bookshelf and lots of them do this). One would think that it would be handy tohave a) a variable containing the chapter number, and b) a variable containing the text of the chapter name without the chapter number. And one would also think that any formatting could be applied to these variables after they had been defined, and that one would have a clear distinction of levels between the definitions of the data (i.e. chapter number, chapter name) and the formatting applied to them in a particular design. I may be missing the obvious, but is there a simple way of doing this, using the LaTeX standard classes?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange. This should be a new question or comment, not an answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/221584)